# How to load and use css file while printing a div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, printing

I need to print a particular div as it is ie whatever css style is there same as that. For styling I am using `bootstrape.css` and `mycss.css` file. But after clicking print all css vanished. Here is my try (implemented one):

```
function printProfile(){            
    var contents = $("#profileContent").html();
    var frame1 = $('<iframe />');

    frame1[0].name = "frame1";
    frame1.css({ "position": "absolute", "top": "-1000000px" }); 
    $("body").append(frame1);

    var frameDoc = frame1[0].contentWindow ? frame1[0].contentWindow : frame1[0].contentDocument.document ? frame1[0].contentDocument.document : frame1[0].contentDocument;

    frameDoc.document.open();
    frameDoc.document.write('<html><head><title>Profile Contents</title>');
    frameDoc.document.write('<link href="css/bootstrape.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />');
    frameDoc.document.write('<link href="css/mycss.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />');
    frameDoc.document.write('</head><body>');
    frameDoc.document.write(contents);
    frameDoc.document.write('</body></html>');
    frameDoc.document.close();

    setTimeout(function () {
        window.frames["frame1"].focus();
        window.frames["frame1"].print();
        frame1.remove();
    }, 100);
}
```

where I am going wrong?

Comment: try with media query css

Comment: i am not very fond of media query. But I tried this:
   @media print
   {
      p {background-color: green;}
   }
for checking purpose. How to use this media query here?

Comment: Note that some browsers do not respect background colors. For example in Firefox the user hast to tick "Print background colors" to allow this. If not necessary use borders, saves on ink and works in all modern browsers.

Answer (score 1):

try media="print" while loading css

```
<link href="css/mycss.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="print"/>
```

Comment: no its not effecting . if i commented .print() method and callinf .open() normally its effecting. But i need it to in print mode.

Comment: write your code for print in   @media print
   {
     
   }